# Discord.py Repeat replies

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My discord bot is repeating the `on_message` reply while they're trying to answer the next prompt.

How do I make each prompt its own separate thing and not get repeated replies? I tried looking it up but I don't know how to word my issues, I tried making more `await`s but that does not really stop the fact that the `on_message` keeps happening each message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxqKA.png

Here is the code :

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    await message.reply("Are you reporting a bug or exploit? State 'bug' or 'exploit'")
    if message.content == 'bug':
        await message.reply("Use the following format:\nUsername:\nBug Report Explanation:\nProof:\nSend streamable files (mp4, Gyazo)")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending "Are you reporting a bug or exploit? State 'bug' or 'exploit'" as a reply to all the messages if they're sent by Discord users, as `if message.author.bot: return` is the only check performed before replying. You need to use [`if-elif-else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)s to make the bot reply accordingly.

Here is one way you could do this (using `if`s):

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    
    if message.content != "bug":
        await message.reply("Are you reporting a bug or exploit? State 'bug' or 'exploit'")
        
    if message.content == 'bug':
        await message.reply("Use the following format:\nUsername:\nBug Report Explanation:\nProof:\nSend streamable files (mp4, Gyazo)")
```

I've wrapped the reply that gets repeated in an `if` that checks and sends it only if the message's content is not "bug". You can change the `if` in the `if message.content == 'bug':` to `elif` (equal to `else if`), as both are the same in this case.

I suggest you learn the basics of Python before using a library like discord.py.

Comment: This was definitely a good start, I realized I wanted to try something else if the word was in the message at all so I learned about "if (word) in message.content:" and "if (word) not in message.content:" Thanks for your help.